# Adding random graphical squares to ArrayList (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing

I want to learn to use ArrayList together with graphical elements in java.

I have a class that creates squares with a random x and a random y position:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Square extends Canvas {

    public int x, y;

    Random r = new Random();


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        x = r.nextInt(640);
        y = r.nextInt(480);


        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);


    }

}
```

And i have a class that creates a JFrame and Add square elements to an ArrayList. But i can't figure it out. I think the solution might be simple and technical, i just need a slight push.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

    public int width, height;
    public String title;

    public JFrame jframe;

    ArrayList<Square> squares  = new ArrayList<Square>();

    public Frame(String title, int width, int height) {

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;



        display();
    }

    public void display() {

        jframe = new JFrame();

        jframe.setTitle(title);
        jframe.setSize(width, height);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            squares.add(new Square());
        }
        jframe.add(squares);

    }



}
```

Comment: Your question needs more information. Can't figure what out?  Are you getting a compile-time or run-time error? If so, what?  Are you getting unexpected behavior?  If so, what did you expect to happen?  What actually happened? etc.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does this compile (doubt - given there is no `JFrame.add(List)` method)? Further, recommend using [lightweight components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769072/differences-between-components-and-lightweight-heavyweight), such as a `JPanel`, rather than a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the Square class and restart.

- Do not have it extend Canvas -- you do not want to unnecessarily mix AWT and Swing
- And your Square class should be a logical class, not a GUI class, meaning it shouldn't extend any GUI component.
- Do not randomize within the painting method.
- Give your Square class x and y int fields
- Give it a `public void draw(Graphics g)` method where it draws itself using the Graphics object passed in.
- Create another class, one that extends JPanel, and give it an `ArrayList<Square>`.
- Override this JPanel's `paintComponent` method.
- In the override be sure to call the super's method.
- In the override, iterate through the array list, calling each Square's draw method.
- Place this JPanel into your JFrame.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you are doing you are adding multiple canvases to the frame which will overlap each other.

Rather create a canvas with a list of Squares(x and y ints) that it draws in its paint and then add one canvas to the frame.

Also I am not sure if JFrame.add() will add the whole canvas and resize it. Rather use a layoutManager to add your components like FlowLayout.
[Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)